# Symfony2 / Session - Set session lifetime

Tags: symfony, session

I need to set session lifetime, now I have in controller this:

```
$request->getSession()->set('name', $form['name']->getData());
```

and in config.yml

```
framework:
   session:
        cookie_lifetime:    31536000
```

But this session expire, after 1 day or if I close the browser? But I need to set session life to 1 year.

In google I found solution, to add cookie_lifetime to config, but still doesn't work.

[image]

How could I do that?

Thanks

Comment: what show Symfony2 profiler to you? what session life time is?

Comment: I edited my questing & added screenshot of profiler.